# sample aws ec2 container services cloud formation template fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup a stack from the sample provided by aws
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html

The stack starts creates a cluser/service/task etc fine except it doest register the ec2 container to my cluster and stack creation eventually fails.

digging into the /var/log/cloud-init-ouput.log I find this

```
+ yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/latest
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://repo.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds')
```

It seems that while the stack is being deployed, it cannot access the network to do a yum install.
Connecting to the box via ssh and running

```
yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
```

works just fine.

Any clue whats stopping the stack from accessing the network while its being deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. just incase someone else falls down this rabbit hole, I did not have a public ip on my subnet. Hence it couldnt connect to the internet